# Detect specific automaticly loaded text files with a terminal browser

Tags: curl, wget, vtt

If you for example user firefox to open an url there can be a lot of text files loaded in the background e.g. with GET method. In my case I call a url with a video and there is a .vtt file loaded for the subtitles.

Is there a way to do this with curl / wget or whatever to get access to automaticly loaded files from a web page? I would be pleased to know which file urls the browser would like to load.

My internet searches weren't successful and I honestly don't know which keywords to search for.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use something like lynx:
lynx -dump -listonly www.yourpage.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As I understand this options of lynx only listing all outgoing links of the page. I am searching for finding out which files are loaded in the background. I could not find an option like this at lynx.

Comment: At least it works with Track Elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track . For all Text File i dont have an solution (Like fetched Text with Ajax and so in)

Comment: Thanx for the info. Well, so it seems there is currently no solution for textfiles automatically loaded by ajax. This is surprising.

Comment: Maybe you could use headless chrome (Puppeteer) with the tabFS extension (TabFS is a browser extension that mounts your browser tabs as a filesystem on your computer. https://omar.website/tabfs/). Then you could visit that page and because the files are in the fs, you could query them as you like

Comment: Well, ok, now I understand how to search for a solution. The keyword is headless browser. It seems to me that PhantomJS could be the solution. thanks.